# EL in JSF-maven project not working

Tags: jsf, el

i'm trying to get my JSF web application to run on JBoss. Til now everthing worked fine, but i can't call methods of my backing bean.

Backing bean:

```
@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class WelcomePM implements Serializable {

public String getHelloStatement() { 
    return "Backing bean works!";
}

}
```

When i tried to invoke the method in a xhtml-page, nothing happened.

Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:body>    
<h:outputText value="JSF works!"></h:outputText>
<h:outputText value="#{welcomePM.getHelloStatement()}" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

The browser only shows the string 'JSF works!' but not the string 'Backing bean works!' as i expected. So i tried to exchange `#{welcomePM.getHelloStatement()}` with something the server can't resolve like `#{fooPM.getBar()}` expecting to get an exception. But there was no exception at all (neither in the browser nor in the server logs). So i believe, that the server doesn't even try to resolve the EL-expression. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried #{welcomePM.helloStatement} ?